# Transistor Amplifier Signal Drops Off Below 200-300Hz

Tags: amplifier, analog, ltspice, high-pass-filter

I tried to build a dual transistor amplifier from a schematic I saw, and used AC Analysis in LT Spice. What I found was that the current and voltage at my simulated 8 ohm speaker load was dropping off well into the AF range. I understand the RC Filter formula, but it seems like I would need some insane value for capacitance in order to properly drive my 8-ohm load. Any suggestions for how I may be able to remedy this? Thank you.

Below is an image of my LT Spice screen. The green line is the current going through the load resistor. The Blue line is the voltage across the same resistor.

[image]

Comment: This is a basic circuit mostly for a learning exercise. If you are using a small speaker, its low frequency response is poor anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The value of C3 is way too low. Calculate using 470uF for -3dB at 43Hz.
I didn't calculate it but I think the value of C2 is also too low. Simulate increasing the values for C2 and C3.

Before looking at its frequency response, why not see if it can produce a sinewave? It can't because there is no way its emitter-follower output transistor with its very high value emitter resistor can drive the very low value 8 ohms load.
Also, the emitter-follower is biased wrong.

I fixed it but without any negative feedback it is very distorted.
[image: 2 transistors]